# Shell appending unknown integer to hostname in prompt (zsh) on mac

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell, zsh, prompt

I recently customized the prompt in my terminal to be more like the one from parrot os, which I really like. I have read over the [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion) many times on how to use the markers/variables in the shell prompt and for a while I had it perfectly the way I wanted it, just like this format:

```
┌─[user@hostname]-[~/current/directory]
└─╼>
```

But recently the prompt has been adding a mysterious integer with a dash right after the hostname, like so:

```
┌─[user@hostname-18]-[~/current/directory]
└─╼>
```

It started with 17, then increased to 18. Now it stays on 18 almost all the time except when I open another terminal instance in which case it jumps to 26. Does anyone know what this number is indicating or why it is appearing here? I have checked to make sure I don't have any other open terminals/shells/emulators. Here is the code from my .zshrc file that I used to customize the prompt:

```
unsetopt PROMPT_SP
PROMPT="┌─[%n@%m]-[%~]"$'\n'"└─╼> "
```

How can I disable that seemingly random number? I have no idea what it is indicating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like that number is, in fact, *your hostname.* Run `hostname` or `uname -n`  to check.

macOS [will do this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343383/how-to-prevent-machine-from-renaming-itself-at-start-up) when it detects a name conflict on your LAN – i.e. it sees that there's another host responding to Bonjour (mDNS) queries for `hostname.local`. (It could be a Linux host running Avahi, too.)

If the numbers just increase indefinitely, this might mean that macOS is reaching *itself* looping back through another interface. (For example, it sends out a query through Wi-Fi and receives it back through wired Ethernet; it responds through Ethernet and the reply travels back through Wi-Fi, making it think it found another device.)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. This is exactly what was happening because I had forgotten to turn my wifi off after plugging in to my ethernet. Simply turning the wifi off and restarting did not fix it, instead I had to rename the machine, reboot, rename to what I originally had, then reboot again and now it's back to normal. The link you posted was very helpful.